# C++ Unable to print the entire list in a that has already been created and read from a text file

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, nodes

Hello I have been having trouble with my program I've created a list and I have the following program

[image]

Its goal is to Read the 5 variables inside the text file 5 variables in 5 different inputs 
so I manage to correctly show the list inside the while loop since every time a line is read it's printed untill .eof(End Of File) 
My goal is that I am trying to print the list OUTSIDE of the while Loop that has already read and printed those 5 variables 10x the problem is that it repeats the last entered 5 Variables in the list
I and repeats that 10x (size of the list)
I've also tried something like this inside the for loop which I found in [here](https://thispointer.com/c-different-ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-of-objects/):

```
int ID=it->ID;
string NAME=it->NAME;
int SEMESTER=it->SEMESTER;
string DIRECTION=it->DIRECTION;
double GRADE=it->GRADE;
```

As if those are nodes but I am a starter with nodes as well as lists and it seems to have failed

Comment: What happens if you try printing`s_stl_list.at(s_stl_list.size())` after the `push_back` call. Also, try a simpler `for (int i=0; i < s_stl_list.size();i++); cout << s_stl_list.at(i) << endl;`

Comment: iterator your are using is not differenced inside the loop. For loop only prints a single object again and again.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, thanks. Code should be posted as text directly in the question (not as a link).

Answer (score 1):

The issue on the left column of code is that you are not de-referencing the iterator. You never set the a_students variable inside the loop, so why do you expect it to change on each iteration?

Write something like:

```
a_students = *it;
```

inside the loop. However there is a simpler way. Instead of manually handling the iterators, use:

```
for (auto a_students: s_stl_list)
{
    // do something with each "a_students" which will be AUTOmatically the right type
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the code you've provided, I see that in your for loop the a_student is used, which is not updated by/with the iterator. Basically you're not looping over the created student list.

Maybe try using `std::for_each` ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)) it will save you a lot of time:) 
Godbolt example: https://godbolt.org/z/fQUhcr